# Displaying data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

Ok. Here is what I'm trying to accomplish.
I am saving the changes to a forms textarea so that all the changes that have been made to that textarea can be viewed. Like a string of comments. I've gotten the data into the two tables. I need help getting it back out.

I have data in two tables "worklog" and "worklognotes".

worklog is a series of work orders from a form that has a textarea is called $spec

worklognotes is a running list of changes that are made to the textarea $spec

In worklognotes I have the id from worklog saved as worklog_id so as changes are made the data will be matched to the right work order.

I can display the information from worklog just fine. But I can't see the info from worklognotes at all. My goal is to display the data from worklognotes and to display the records in worklognotes WHERE worklognotes.worklog_id = worklog.id

I hope this makes sense. Writing it out like this has helped.

Here is the query statements I'm using. Thanks for your help.

```
$connection=mysql_connect ("localhost", "foo", "bar") or die ("I cannot connect to the database.");
$db=mysql_select_db ("database", $connection) or die (mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT * FROM worklog WHERE id=$id LIMIT 0,1";
$sql_result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die (mysql_error());

$connection2=mysql_connect ("localhost", "foo", "bar") or die ("I cannot connect to the database.");
$db=mysql_select_db ("database", $connection2) or die (mysql_error());
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM worklognotes,worklog WHERE worklognotes.worklog_id=worklog.id ORDER BY worklog_id DESC";
$sql_result2 = mysql_query($query2, $connection2) or die (mysql_error());
```

-- cont -- 09-13-10

ok here is the modified query

`$connection = mysql_connect ("localhost", "adsites_seth", "callie") or die ("I cannot connect to the database.");
$db = mysql_select_db ("adsites_cerebra", $connection) or die (mysql_error());`

`$query = "SELECT * FROM worklog ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN worklognotes ON worklog_id = worklognotes.worklog_id ";
$query .= "WHERE worklog.id=worklognotes.worklog_id ORDER BY worklognotes.worklog_id ASC";`

`$sql_result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die (mysql_error());`

I have four entries in the worklognotes table and all four are displaying on one page.
I only need the one entry that belong to the worklog I'm viewing and if the is no entry. Display nothing.

Comment: Does the second query fail, or both queries?  Do you get any error information output, or just no results KingMob?

Comment: You realise that you don't need separate database connections for each table that you need to access? In fact, it's a big overhead.

Comment: If you have access, you should consider testing your queries in the mysql cli, quicker that way. Updated answer. If this answers your initial question but you have more, consider asking them separately.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand (correct me if I'm wrong), you have a 'one to many' relationship between worklog and worklongnotes.

If this is indeed the case, then you want a query that will give you rows 'joined' by worklog.id.

Untested, the following example should be of use:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect ("localhost", "foo", "bar") or die ("I cannot connect to the database.");
$db = mysql_select_db ("database", $connection) or die (mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM worklog ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN worklognotes ON worklog.id = worklognotes.worklog_id ";
$query .= "WHERE worklog.id=$id ORDER BY worklognotes.worklog_id ASC";

$sql_result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

Which could give something like:

```
SELECT * FROM worklog LEFT JOIN worklognotes ON worklog.id = worklognotes.worklog_id 
WHERE worklog.id=1 ORDER BY worklognotes.worknotes_id ASC;

+-------------+----------------+----------------------------------------+
| id          |  worknotes_id  | log                                    |
+-------------+----------------+----------------------------------------+
| 1           | 1              | Houses atre grate                      | 
| 1           | 2              | Houses are grate                       | 
| 1           | 3              | Houses are great                       | 
| 2           | 4              | Shop5 are smelly                       | 
| 2           | 5              | Shops are smelly                       | 
| 2           | 6              | Shopes aren't smelly                   | 
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

To get all worklognotes for a given worklog.id:

```
SELECT * FROM worklog LEFT JOIN worklognotes ON worklog.id = worklognotes.worklog_id 
WHERE worklog.id=1 AND worklog.id = 1 ORDER BY worklognotes.worknotes_id ASC;

+-------------+----------------+----------------------------------------+
| id          |  worknotes_id  | log                                    |
+-------------+----------------+----------------------------------------+
| 1           | 1              | Houses atre grate                      | 
| 1           | 2              | Houses are grate                       | 
| 1           | 3              | Houses are great                       | 
+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I think the AND should be a WHERE... otherwise you pull all worklog entries and only the worklognotes are limited to the correct id.

Comment: And, @KingMob, if you only want the most recent entry from worknotes, you can add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query. (The table displayed is ordered like `worknotes_id ASC`, but the query given uses `DESC`, so the first record will actually be the most recent.)

Comment: grossvogel, how much would you charge to become my personal SO editor?